# Is there a plugin for this type of img link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, animation, jquery-plugins

I was wordring what type of JQ plugins this is ?

http://www.gravitatedesign.com/web-design-portfolio#filter=*

If you click on the links at the top

```
All Work
Featured Work
Design
CMS
Animation
Branding
Client List
```

The images is animated around the site. How do you make this?

Comment: Might I suggest using your browser's web tools (Web Inspector, Firebug, Dragonfly...) and looking at the included scripts (access with F12 in most browsers). Had you tried this you could've answered this yourself. Voting to close as 'off-topic,' as it's *not* a [programming question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)/problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like Isotope to me.
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/